# Porting from ASP.NET MVC 5 to dotnet core 2 : possible replacement for System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core-2.0

While porting an application from ASP.NET MVC 5 to dotnet core 2, we are getting an error wherever `System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult` was being used, this method is explained clearly in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx).

However the namespace `System.Web.Mvc` does not exist in dotnet core 2, what's a recommeneded replacement for `System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult` for porters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793834/41284 solved the issue, using StatusCodeResult(param). This question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following namespaces:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.StatusCode`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes`

and you can return a status code like this:

```
return  StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```